# MVVM-Light-Toolkit: EventToCommand for Windows 8.1 App available?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am developing a Windows 8.1 App using VS 2013 Professional, MVVM-Light Toolkit and C#/Xaml.

I am trying to pass a clicked object to a second page when a Grid-View-Item is clicked. The first thing I wanted to do is implement the EventToCommand-Behavior but research showed me that this won't work in a Windows 8 App.

My question now is: Is there any recent information about the EventToCommand-Behavior being available for Windows 8.1 Apps at the moment? The source I got that information from is more than a year old and I somehow can't find more recent information.

Lets assume there is no EventToCommand for Windows 8.1 Apps - is there an elegant workaround? I am kind of confused by all of the information I got and that is why I am asking here to get some things cleared up. The following code I tried recently does not work and results in a crash without exception message:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
        <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Main.GoToDetailsPageCommand, 
                                            Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
    </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This really is the last piece that is left for me to understand the whole concept of mvvm practically and theoretically.

**Edit:** Solved the problem. I used the wrong CommandParameter.

Comment: Can't you add the command to the item without using an event?

Comment: Hey, I don't know if I got you right but the gridView does not have a Command-Property. That is why I have to convert the "ItemClick-Event" to a Command.

Comment: If you have a solution to your own problem, please make it an answer so people in the future will find the answer faster. And please avoid using [solved] in your title.